# Unable to use 'dpkg' to install .deb file in linux

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, dpkg

I am trying to install google-chrome in AWS amplify build setting, the .deb file is installed at the location but the issue occurs when I try to install it using :

`dpkg -i <packagename>.deb`

I have tried `dpkg -i <packagename>.deb` to install the google-chrome package in AWS Amplify.

I got an error :
`error : dpkg command not found`

What I can use as an alternative to install .deb file ?

Comment: Follow the instructions for the distro you are running.